# Parse ISO 8601 date time from JSON object to local time

Tags: json.net

I have a Json object that was returned from my other process, the content of the object as below:

```
{
  "nextDrawTime": "2017-07-10T05:33:44.914Z",
  "winnerSelectionProcess": {
    "mode": "idle"
  }
}
```

My problem is, when I parsing this object using Json.NET like this, it returned wrong date time:

```
dynamic Jobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myJson);

Console.Write(Jobj["nextDrawTime"].ToString());
```

The date time out put is: 15/07/2017 5:33:44 AM, which is wrong, how do convert this back to local time?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setting [`DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDateTimeZoneHandling.htm) when deserializing.  As explained in the [docs](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DateTimeZoneHandling.htm), this setting will

> Treat [dates and times] as local time. If the DateTime object represents a Coordinated
>   Universal Time (UTC), it is converted to the local time.

I.e.:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local,
};

dynamic Jobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myJson, settings);
```

Or, you could always call [`DateTime.ToLocalTime()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolocaltime(v=vs.110).aspx) after parsing:

```
var localNextDrawTime = ((DateTime)Jobj["nextDrawTime"]).ToLocalTime();
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/M51CD3) (where the problem is a little hard to reproduce since [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net)'s local time is, in fact, UTC.)